# Hide dotnet linker warning

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have updated a linux C# project to use .NET6, however Oracle package has not been updated yet and generates warnings when I publish the project:

```
dotnet publish worker -c Release --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained -p:PublishTrimmed=true -p:SuppressTrimAnalysisWarnings=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false -o bin
...
ILLink : warning IL2105: System.String Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection::ConnectionString(): Type 'System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor' was not found in the caller assembly nor in the base library. Type name strings used for dynamically accessing a type should be assembly qualified. [/tmp/worker/worker.csproj]
```

I didn't find a way to disable these annoying warnings (for now I don't care if Oracle connections don't work, but I don't want to remove Oracle library references if it builds fine).

Comment: What are you using? Visual studio ? or just a CMD?

Comment: dotnet cli with a csproj on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .csproj file in a `<PropertyGroup>`, insert `<ILLinkWarningLevel>4</ILLinkWarningLevel>` and compile. Setting it to a higher warning level (such as `5`) restores the warnings.

Sources: [Trimming options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options#warning-versions) and [C# Compiler Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#warninglevel)